# Mednafen Troubleshooting (specifacally SNES and Gameboy Advance)

Tags: emulation, troubleshooting

I am trying to use mednafen and mednafee to run retro games on my raspberry pi.  The NES games work great, and so do the Gameboy Color and Gameboy games, but I am having trouble with the SNES and GBA games.  The SNES games run, but they run really slow and the sound is all messed up.  On the GBA, I downloaded the Rom Image and made it so that it opened it, but it only loads the startup screen, and then nothing else.  I haven't been able to find this information anywhere else.  I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V1.2 if that helps.  I also have not used raspberry pis, or Linux, or any other type of computer like this before.
Edit: GBA games are working, see the comment I made below, still having troubles with SNES, and everything else there still applies

Comment: I think for SNES and GBA games you need some other kind of config file along with the ROM...

Comment: Like what?  I am unsure of what exactly I need...

Comment: I'm not sure, but when I was watching a video about how to setup retropie, they mentioned for some games you needed  a Rom and some kind of config file, I forget what it was called...

Comment: Ok.  What video was it?  If you find it, what config file is it?

Comment: I'll let you know if I find it, I forget which video it was now.

Comment: I got GBA games to work :D.  All I needed to do was go to the sav file in the mednafen directory (home/pi/.mednafen) and to the .sav file of the game that wasn't working.  I renamed the file replacing the .sav part and all the numbers before with simply ".type".  Then I opened up with leafpad, or any other text editor, and typed in "flash 128".  I don't know if that part affected anything, but I did it anyway.  I still am having trouble with SNES games though, so please help with that :\

Comment: Alright... I really have no idea what to do, but I'll let you know if I figure it out @Alex